# iPhone Development: Resources for beginners

Tags: iphone

As the title says have you got any available resource to start developing for iPhones?

Books, Online resources, tools, development environment, pre-requisites and everything is related to iPhone programming will be good!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development, Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Comment: See also [Are you doing iPhone development? How do you learn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405568/are-you-doing-iphone-development-how-do-you-learn) and [What are the best Cocoa-Touch/iPhone programming blogs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232570/what-are-the-best-cocoa-touch-iphone-programming-blogs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are a beginner, for books, this list is a good place to start

http://cocoadevblog.com/objective-c-cocoa-iphone-programming-books

Apple and Stanford have a free class in iTunes that you can download and follow along. It is taught by Apple engineers to beginners.

http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225

Finally apple has a wealth of reference and tutorial type information.

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: As said by the duke: Absolute Beginners! Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your looking into doing. But the developer site always has lots of examples and all of the methods/class/references you can use.

http://developer.apple.com/

Of course you can always post questions or search them on google/stackoverflow.

If your looking for like books, you can check out the public library. Free books for reference are always good.

Comment: I would like to create a client application for a web application that is already in production to give my customers a better experience using iPhones...

Answer (score 0):

I just recently started programming for iPhone as well so I can pass on the resources that have helped me immensely.

eBooks:

- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Essentials
- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_4_Development_Essentials_Xcode_4_Edition

Tutorials:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/

The eBooks I have linked are both absolutely fantastic and one of the few xCode 4.0 books that I was able to find that seemed to be of an actual usable quality. They both contain easy to follow and clear tutorials on simple and more advanced aspects of programming for iOS.

Ray's site is an immensely helpful resource as it contains both a very active forum base for iOS programming in addition to a constantly growing tutorial collection as there are 4-5 people that constantly are creating new tutorials that the community votes on and suggests every week. It contains some more advanced topics than the above books and I would recommend looking at it after doing a few walk through/tutorials from the books.

You are also on a pretty good site already for clarifying questions you cannot find covered elsewhere :D

Best of luck!
-Karoly