# iPad SDK Tutorials

Tags: objective-c, ipad, sdk

Do you know a great place to find tutorials for dev to iPad ?

```
Like custom view controllers, split views ... this things ...

Cause I search on google but google changes "ipad" per "iphone", and I did't find big things in documentation...

Please help-me...

PS: Sorry, my English sucks...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [iPhone Development: Resources for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240739/iphone-development-resources-for-beginners/6791614#6791614)

My answer from above question for ease:

I just recently started programming for iPhone(Though final product is targeted for iPad) as well so I can pass on the resources that have helped me immensely.

eBooks:

```
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Essentials
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_4_Development_Essentials_Xcode_4_Edition
```

Tutorials:

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/
```

The eBooks I have linked are both absolutely fantastic and one of the few xCode 4.0 books that I was able to find that seemed to be of an actual usable quality. They both contain easy to follow and clear tutorials on simple and more advanced aspects of programming for iOS.

Ray's site is an immensely helpful resource as it contains both a very active forum base for iOS programming in addition to a constantly growing tutorial collection as there are 4-5 people that constantly are creating new tutorials that the community votes on and suggests every week. It contains some more advanced topics than the above books and I would recommend looking at it after doing a few walk through/tutorials from the books.

You are also on a pretty good site already for clarifying questions you cannot find covered elsewhere :D

Now for the bit specific to your question, like rafa said, iPhone and iPad programming are ,for all intents and purposes, identical. There are certain things like the SplitViewController that are only available on iPad but if you need to use those a google search with the relevant terms will yield the correct tutorials(The links I have provided also include examples on SplitViewControllers). If you have more specific iPad sdk questions provide an explanation of what you are trying to do and I'm sure the community can try to help you out.

Best of luck! -Karoly

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Developer.apple.com

And iPad and iPhone dev are essentially the same